# Datebox JqueryMobile- How to highlight today's date.

Tags: jquery-mobile, datebox

I have a problem with Datebox plugin- When I open it, today's date is not highlighted, futhermore. I set "calHighToday" option to true but it keeps on without highlighting today's date.

```
<input name="fechaPartido" id="fechaPartido" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox", "calHighToday":true,"overrideCalStartDay": 1}'
```

I set up the datebox plugin with:

```
<script src="js/jqm-datebox.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jqm-datebox.mode.calbox.min.js"></script><<
<script src="js/jquery.mobile.datebox.i18n.es-ES.utf8.js"></script>
```

and the css with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jqm-datebox.min.css" />
```

I downloaded the current version of the plugin from http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/demos/install.html.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: can you have jsfiddle for this?

Comment: Just created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/4RKQ8/1/ It seems to work correctly, at least in chrome desktop... Does the fiddle work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fiddle

jsfiddle.net/manuelfc/d5wP2/

Is has to be something related with my custom theme, since, when I remove it, everything works ok.

You can check it in external files.